# When trying to run this "ng serve" command in angular 5 project this error occurs

Tags: node.js, npm, angular5

module.js:557
        throw err;

```
Error: Cannot find module C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:190:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:662:3
```

This is the error that appears while running 'ng serve'.

Comment: Welcome! I think you are going to need to give us more context. Is this error happening at the command line, or in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Angular CLI isn't installed.

`npm install -g @angular/cli`